# concat space in php codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

My select query is always prompting an error even i already put a FALSE at the end of it.

```
function preparedBy($series){
    $this->db->select('CONCAT (users.FirstName,' ',users.MiddleName,' ',users.LastName) as name',FALSE);
    $this->db->from ( 'users' );
    $this->db->join ( 'entry ', 'entry.ClericalAide = users.UserName');
    $this->db->where ( 'entry.Series', $series);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

this is the error as i hover in my  sql select 
[image]

Comment: Can you also attach the error?

Comment: i updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are all messed up. Try running this:

```
function preparedBy($series){
    $this->db->select('CONCAT (users.FirstName, users.MiddleName, users.LastName) as name',FALSE);
    $this->db->from ('users');
    $this->db->join ('entry','entry.ClericalAide = users.UserName');
    $this->db->where ('entry.Series', $series);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I already found the answer.

Comment: $this->db->select("CONCAT(users.FirstName,' ',users.MiddleName,' ',users.LastName) as name",FALSE);

Comment: Scratch the last one, I just realized that you're concatenating names and you're gonna want a space in between...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function to this

```
function preparedBy($series){
$this->db->select('CONCAT (users.FirstName,'". ."',users.MiddleName,'". ."',users.LastName) as name",FALSE);
$this->db->from ( 'users' );
$this->db->join ( 'entry ', 'entry.ClericalAide = users.UserName');
$this->db->where ( 'entry.Series', $series);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `" "` and not `' '`.

```
function preparedBy($series){
    $this->db->select('CONCAT (users.FirstName," ",users.MiddleName," ",users.LastName) as name',FALSE);
    $this->db->from ( 'users' );
    $this->db->join ( 'entry ', 'entry.ClericalAide = users.UserName');
    $this->db->where ( 'entry.Series', $series);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```